When Did They Start Using Ohm's Triangle for Arithmetic Topics?
I am here with a historical question about maths education.  I hope I have chosen the right SE as there are confusingly three that pertain to historical research into mathematics.
Any quantitative relationships where one quantity is the product of other two can be expressed by placing the symbol for the first quantity on top of the symbols of other two:
$$
 \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{M}{D \space\space V}
$$
In the above $M$ stands for mass, $D$ for density, and $V$ for volume.  If you cover $V$ with your finger, for example, the remaining part can be seen as $\frac{M}{D}$ and you will know that the volume of a given substance can be obtained by dividing its mass by its density.  Cheat sheets of this type are many (not knowing the term, I'd tentatively call them quantities triangles): There are triangles for percentage, speed-distance-time, and capacitance.
All quantities triangles go back to that of Ohm's law proposed by Herbert M. Pilkington in 1892:
$$
 \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{E}{C \space\space R}
$$
My question is: When did they start using quantities triangles for teaching arithmetic topics, especially speed and percent?  I know T. Teahan proposed a percent triangle in 1979, but this may not be the earliest attestation.  If there are pre-Teahan examples in other languages, they would be good to know too.

Honestly, I've never seen such a thing in my life.  But that is not surprising, as this appears to be something that one would see in physics, and not mathematics.  I'm not sure that this is really on-topic here.  It might be on-topic at [physics.se].

It is a maths education topic.  A mnemonic developed by electricians was appropriated by primary education teachers to give children cheat sheets for percentage and speed (see for the latter; https://thirdspacelearning.com/gcse-maths/ratio-and-proportion/speed-distance-time-triangle/).

Also never seen or heard of that. Skeptical it's very widespread.

The only place I've seen this is with quaternion multiplication and similar behaviors. I have not seen widespread adoption of something like this outside of cyclic phenomena.

I recommend you move this to the History of Science and math SE site:  https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

I beg for a little more patience. HSM doesn't even have a tag for primary education.  Primary school maths questions may be rare in MESE but they'd be rarer in HSM. Quantities triangles are one of ways how teaching maths went wrong at primary school. Remember the outrage higher education people had for https://x.com/CarstenPaul1982/status/1384734904869703681 ?

Suppose if I asked when they started teaching multiplication to an 8 y.o. as if the order of numbers had a linguistic meaning.  If this question is for MESE, then my thread too belongs here.  Regardless of how one thinks about these methods, they are taught systematically at primary education (albeit triangles are less used).

Is it really true that you teach soirrf time distance law in primary school= So what ages are in primary school? Om Germany it is 6 to 10-

Widespread enough that it's seen in multiple places around the world down to at least early high school, this is very definitely a mathematics education question and topic.

Let's elaborate further the widespreadness of this: I'm from Belgium and I've never heard of this. (In which parts of the world seems this to be common knowledge?)

@Nij Can you provide any evidence that it is used in mathematics?  The examples given in the question here are all physics / dimensional analysis problems, which are generally not taught as part of the mathematics curriculum (in the US---the common core has one or two items regarding unit conversion, but nothing obvious in the vein of this question:  https://www.thecorestandards.org/Math/Content/MD/ ).  It is incumbent on the asker to demonstrate the use of the method in mathematics, and they have (thus far) failed to do so.

@Dominique Teahan is somehow mangled into Techan in Tagalog.  See, e.g., this Filippino YouTuber who teaches "Techan's triangle" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jdNteY3GQE.  Searching for "prozentrechnung pyramide" reveals quite a lot of triangles in German.  There are a lot of Japanese triangles too.  For English, consult Teahan (1979 linked above) or search for "percent triangle".

What, my own teaching experience and observation of other teachers isn't enough? @XanderHenderson since when has that requirement been enforced, and why is it only when users from the USA push back that someone has to provide evidence that way?

https://www.google.com/search?q=multiplication+triangles+worksheet popped up a bunch of results, either worksheets or cards (often for sale) with triangles where number factors and a product either have the missing operations or one missing value to fill in.

The BBC has pages specifically under math education using this technique for speed-distance-time relatrionships.

@Nij You didn't say anything about your own experience.  You wrote one sentence, asserting "Widespread enough that it's seen in multiple places around the world down to at least early high school, this is very definitely a mathematics education question and topic."  You did not claim anything about personal experience, nor did you back up that assertion in any way.  Had you instead said "Well, I am from [country] and have taught this at [levels]", I would not have objected.

A person asserting they have also seen something would be exactly sharing their personal experience, in the absence of proffering another explanation. This is again a very weird thing to quibble about, purely because it doesn't match your own experience or those of a biased commentsry group. @XanderHenderson

Again, @Nij, you did not say that you had seen it.  You asserted that it was widespread.

No, I stated it was "widespread enough", the obvious implication is that it's widespread enough I personally have encountered it from 'over here' as well.

@XanderHenderson To demonstrate the use of the method in mathematics in America; here is a possibly pre-Teahan material. Steiner, R. (1993). An Alternative Method for Teaching Percents: The Percent "T". Method to Your Mathness. A Teacher Resource Manual for ABE/GED Mathematics Teachers, 3-14.  https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED362672.pdf. Steiner worked in andragogy, and she seems to have started resorting Ts at around 1982.  Appendix A lists several Ts from real estate industry.

This reminds me of the top-voted answer to this question. It it similar enough to what you’re looking for in a purely mathematical setting?

3³＝3×3×3＝27
³8＝³√8＝2
₂1024＝log₂1024＝10
This is a notation I have seen previously for your question, @NickC.  Alas, these are too interesting for my really mundane one.  A key person who introduced quantities circle is Marilyn Floberg with her book _Practice in Real Estate Mathematics
_, first published probably in 70s.  I still don't know where she got the ideas from.  I am afraid to order her book from aboard after losing a fourth book to mail accidents.   Anyone who can volunteer for research on the ground?
